# How can Autowire library (Scalajs) perform more than one HTTP method type in doCall?

Tags: scala.js

Looking at the examples and reading through documentations of lihaoyi's Autowire library for ScalaJs, I can't see a way that one autowire.Client can perform both GET and POST as it only allows overriding the doCall:

```
def doCall(req: Request): Future[PickleType]
```

And request is simply just:

```
  case class Request[PickleType](path : Seq[String], args: Map[String, PickleType])
```

Is there a nice solution (other than having multiple autowire.Client instances) to this limitation so that my api can follow the GET for getting, POST and UPDATE for creating and updating (REST convention)?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your exact requirements, but keep in mind that *inside* `doCall` you can potentially do different calls depending on the circumstances. For example, [in Querki](https://github.com/jducoeur/Querki/blob/master/querki/scalajs/src/main/scala/querki/client/Client.scala#L78-L99) my `doCall` implementation looks like this:

```
override def doCall(req: Request): Future[String] = {
  try {
    if (DataAccess.space.isEmpty) {
      makeCall(req, controllers.ClientController.rawApiRequest())
    } else {
      makeCall(req, controllers.ClientController.apiRequest(
        DataAccess.userName, 
        DataAccess.spaceId.underlying))
    }
  } catch {
    ...
  }
}
```

This is choosing the API to call based on external runtime information, but you could introspect the `Request`, and decide what API to call that way. I suspect that's what you are looking for.

It does require some external information telling you which Request corresponds to which method, but I don't see much way around that -- Autowire isn't inherently about HTTP (and it's pretty common for all Autowire calls to go to a single HTTP entry point), so you're doing something rather out of the ordinary here. If you're using Play, I believe you can get the method information from the JavascriptReverseRouter; if not, you should see whether your HTTP implementation provides any sort of introspection that you can use...